# Porting C++ __fastcall Hook from x86 to x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, 64-bit

I have this hook function that works fine on x86. Thanks to Bo Persson.

```
void __fastcall Hook(Class* ThisInECX, int UnknownEDX, OtherClass* P1, void* P2, void* P3)
{
    static void* OriginalFunctionPointer = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("Some.dll"), "[...]");
    static auto OriginalFunction = ((void(__fastcall*)(Class* ThisInECX, int UnknownEDX, OtherClass* P1, void* P2, void* P3))OriginalFunctionPointer);

    OriginalFunction(ThisInECX, UnknownEDX, P1, P2, P3);
}
```

Now I'm trying to port it to x64. What I found and understood from a few snippets is that:
I had another variable "int UnknownRDX" at front but without it at atleast called the OriginalFunction correctly.
My real variables (P1 etc) seem to be somehow offsetted (or my problem is something different).
I actually need to know if this declaration is right so I can look for the problem at even worse positions.

```
void Hook(Class* This, int Unknown0, int Unknown1, OtherClass* P1, void* P2, void* P3)
{
    static void* OriginalFunctionPointer = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("Some64.dll"), "[...]");
    static auto OriginalFunction = ((void(*)(Class* This, int Unknown0, int Unknown1, OtherClass* P1, void* P2, void* P3))OriginalFunctionPointer);

    // Using P1 here is fine on x86 but not on x64

    OriginalFunction(This, Unknown0, Unknown1, P1, P2, P3)
}
```

Comment: Please don't put any tags in the title. Mkay that would be great, thanks.

Comment: just a suggestion... use `size_t UnknownEDX` in both x86 and x64.

Comment: could it be that the signature for x64 is void(Class *, int64_t, OtherClass *, void *, void *) and not void(Class *, int, int, OtherClass *, void *, void *)?

Comment: @Tomek: Doesn't change anything as far as I can judge that.

Comment: Well, it depends on calling conventions. gcc uses registers for integer parameters and two ints will take two registers and shuffle the remaining parameters by one in this case (the ints will take lower 32 bits of two registers, int64_t will take one 64 bits register). I don't know ABI for VC on x64 so this may or may not be the issue. Also when passing through stack endianness and data alignment may come into play.

Comment: __fastcall on x86 uses two cpu register (ecx and edx).  x64 uses four cpu registers.  Avoid reinventing this wheel by using Detours: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

Comment: I'm using EasyHook which does the hooking for both x86 and x64. It just seems to not make my life easier for the hook function declaration. Detours only supports x86 in the free version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one calling convention on x64, so you can ditch that from the signature. What's likely going wrong is that you're trying to load the x86 version of a procedure from an x64 function.

Edit: Oh wait, you posted that question about x86/x64 hooking before, right? I'm pretty confident that's not the problem here.

What I would say is that previously, your code depended on calling-convention specific hacks, but on x64 there is only one calling convention.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx

Comment: It's a x64 library I'm loading from.

Comment: More about calling convention : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx

Comment: @zEh: Well, judging by some of the names of your arguments, I'm simply guessing that you don't actually know the signature of the function you're trying to hook.

Comment: @DeadMG: I do know them but I prefer using abstract names.

Comment: @zEh: It would be easier for us if you would post the real signature.

Comment: @zEh: If you want to intercept a virtual call, you're really going to need to use regular inheritance. Oh, and the same compiler, too. Those things are not C-interface safe.